# Не правильные данные получаю, а в чем причина - не могу понять

Tags: c#

Работаю с панелью оператора ОВЕН СП307, получаю данные из системных регистром Modbus, и есть момент, который не могу решить:

Некоторые данные выводятся возможно некорректно, может я их не правильно обрабатываю, но выглядит по итогу вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Октеты маски подсети могут принимать значения от 0 до 255, а у меня выходит 8227, и таких примеров много, что в таком случае можно сделать?
Если что, код для сбора информации выглядит вот так:

```
int[] reg1_PFW_PO = modClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(4096, 120);
Reg_PFW_PO.Items.Add("Номер стартового экрана:" + ((UInt16)reg1_PFW_PO[0]));
```

Первой строчкой беру из определенных регистров данные, а второй добавляю их в listbox.
Библиотека, с которой работаю - EasyModbus.

Я думал, что проблема в том, что я неверные регистры читаю, и пробовал редактировать код, но этот вариант не сработал.
я пробовал в первую строчку вместо 4096 писать 10000 и 14096, и вышло следующее:

10000:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

14096:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что надо в итоге сделать, чтобы данные были корректными?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге нужно точно узнать протокол обмена информацией, то есть в каком регистре что находится и в каком формате.

Дальше нужно взять какую-то готовую программу для обмена по MODBUS:

ModLinkDemo – serial master/slave application

MODBus_TEST – TCP client

mod_RSsim – TCP server

CCS Modbus Simulator – serial master/slave application

и попробовать с её помощью вручную читать регистры.

Когда проторкол обмена станет ясен, тогда уже можно переходить к программированию.

Comment: Это все есть, программу сам писал, именно считывание вызывает проблемы, оно по какой то причине идёт неправильно, вот это и хотелось бы узнать, что делать, чтобы оно происходило корректно

Comment: Протокол обмена Modbus TCP, на эту железку есть на сайте также карта регистров

Comment: Но вам удалось с помощью готовых утилит правильно считать данные? Если да, то дальше можно действовать методом сниффинга: посмотреть, как проходит обмен утилитой, а потом - как программой. Сразу будет понятно, что с программой не так.

Comment: Утилиты не помогли, использовал модуляторы но результата они не дали, получается тоже самое

Comment: значит, нет понимания в карте регистров. Нужно добится обмена с помощью любой из утилит. Дайте, пожалуста, ссылку на карту регистров на сайте.

Comment: [https://owen.ru/uploads/251/sp3xx_rp_2.1.pdf] вот та железка, с которой я работаю, карта регистров там, со страницы 196 начало

Comment: Меня интересуют регистры PFW, с остальными все нормально, именно с PFW у меня проблемы

Comment: Но вопрос тогда не сюда, это не связано с программированием. Есть форумы АСУТП, можно и в техподдержку обратиться. А руководство я посмотрю, мне интересно. Если что-то найду - сообщу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо